# Node js question about debugging - Using Koa for Cadence-web

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, koa, inspect, cadence-workflow

I started the debugger using :

$ node  --inspect ../cadence-web/server/routes.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e470a53c-480b-497e-8494-5f1ea62f3b38

Now - I inspect chrome: The code is successfully opened in the debugger.
Please see link below

[image: Debug Open]

I open dedicated devTools for Node

Please see link below
I go to localhost:9229: The site cannot be reached.

[image: Debugger]

Any help will be appreciated.

What am I doing incorrectly. Why is the code not loaded on localhost: 9229

Answer (score 0):

The port mentioned in the startup is the **Debugger** port where the Debugger (Web Tools or VSCode etc.) listens to node. It is **not** the port your web server is using. That port hasn't changed from its setting in code. Check your source, it should be there, something like 3000 or 8080, depending on your framework and settings